# Horizontal scroll text not resetting to start position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, text

I am creating a simple horizontal text scroll field for my game. I've set it up with a `ScrollRect` component but I also want the text to scroll horizontally on its own.

The `ScrollRect` works fine, I can drag the text back and fourth. However, the simple test scroll script I created based of [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Marquee) script, while it moves the text fine, it isn't resetting the texts position once its off the screen.

Note - I don't actually mean the entire screen, I am referring to the area in which the text is view-able: [image: Diagram]

My Code:

```
void OnGUI ()
{
    if (isPaused) ScrollMusicText();
}

private void ScrollMusicText ()
{
    if (width == 0) width = musicText.textBounds.extents.x * 2;

    musicText.rectTransform.position = new Vector3(musicText.rectTransform.position.x - MUSIC_TEXT_SCROLL_SPEED, musicText.rectTransform.position.y, musicText.rectTransform.position.z);
    if (musicText.rectTransform.position.x > -width) musicText.rectTransform.position = new Vector3(width, musicText.rectTransform.position.y, musicText.rectTransform.position.z);
}
```

My thinking behind the script is that `textBounds.extents.x` * 2 is about the same length as the text. Therefore, once the text (either via scrolling or player movement) reaches `-width` it will be out of the view area and its position can be set to the other side of the view area so it call scroll back through.

However the `if (musicText.rectTransform.position.x > -width)` statement seems to be firing every `OnGUI` call and I don't understand why.

Furthermore, the `musicText.rectTransform.position = new Vector3(width, musicText.rectTransform.position.y, musicText.rectTransform.position.z);` statement isn't actually moving the text, in fact it just seems to be completely stopping all movement.

---

Notes:

- The `ScrollRect`'s movement is Unrestricted.
- `musicText` is TextMeshPro with a `ContentSizeFitter` (set to Horizontal: Preferred Size) component attached.
- `musicText`'s start position is `x` 0.

Comment: Further, you debug this anytime by enabling the debugger and single-stepping the code. Then hovering the mouse over variables shows their values inside VisualStudio.
Breaking long lines into several smaller ones may help here.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the `transform.position`, the `rectTransform.position` is a world-coordinates position. Or in case of the UI canvas, the locatin on the whole canvas, not just inside your box.

So it depends on the position of not only that textitem, but also the panel around and every other item up the hierarchy.

For that text movement you wish to make, I suggest to work only with the localPosition, which is relative to the parent. So you can move you UI box later without this affecting the working of the scrolltext.